# Why is my JS putting a prefix to my links (localhost:3000/mylink)?

Tags: javascript

My JS is putting a prefix to my links, and it shouldn't, because it's pure html + js.

```
var source3 = 
'<img class="col-3 small-brand-avatar" src="assets/mimub.jpg" >'
+ '<div class="quarter_padding_left col-8">'
+ '<h5 class="medium">'
+ tooltipsInfo[2].name 
+ '</h5>'
+ '<span class="lightgray">de </span>'
+ '</span>'
+ tooltipsInfo[2].location
+ '</br>'
+ tooltipsInfo[2].price 
+ '<a href="​http://clk.tradedoubler.com">'
+ '<span class="green"> Mimub</span>'
+ '</a>'
+ '</br>'
+ '</div>';
```

When clicking in my link , the following URL is rendered:

```
http://localhost:3000/http://clk.tradedoubler.com/
```

Thanks

Comment: With your given html it shouldn't be, are you sure the url is the same in your actual code? could something else be interacting with this code?

Comment: how are you putting source3 into your dom?

Comment: It'll be your browser prefixing the URL because it thinks its a relative link, what browser are you using?

Comment: $("#tp_tp_" + "3").html(source3);

Comment: At the moment, the code you have won't run and, if it did, there wouldn't be a link to click on because you never generate a DOM from it. You need to provide a reduced test case that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `</br>`? You don't have a start tag for your end tag, and that element has forbidden end tags anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a character in your code (between `"` and `http://...`) that is not being picked up by editors which makes your URL invalid. Retype your `a` tag:

```
+ '<a href="http://clk.tradedoubler.com">'
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. +1, but I'm voting to close the question due to a typo.

Comment: Good spot. [That character is](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html) U+200B : ZERO WIDTH SPACE

Comment: Yeah go ahead @j08691